# Auto slice an image file based on transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have multiple small icons in a single file. They are separated with transparency. So I can manually select them and save individually. But this takes long time with many parts. 
Is it possible to automatically save each non-transparent piece to separate file?

Comment: Why don't you use slices? You would only need to create them once, and then you can save them indefinitely..

Comment: if this is for a web site, you may not want to slice them at all and instead make it part of a CSS Sprite.

Comment: Is your icons on seperate layers? Or you ordered them side by side? By the way, CSS Sprite is may be a good idea.

Comment: They are side by side. Single layer. Need them in separate files (for placing on UI buttons).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it depends on what you've got there.

1. If **all icons reside on separat, individual layers**, that's pretty easy. Go to your menu and select...

   > File > Scripts > Export Layers To Files

   For your purposes, you'll most probably want to make sure you have the *"Trim Layers"* option checked.
2. If **all your icons are on a single, transparent layer**, it's easy too. You can use the regular *"Save for Web & Devices"* and export all slices as images in one go. To create slices, simply use the *"slice tool"* to select the individual icon areas.

   [image: slice tool]

   [image: export steps]